# R - Infinite or missing values in 'x'

Tags: r, svd

I'm getting  `Error in svd(x, nu = 0L, nv = 0L) : infinite or missing values in 'x'` when trying to calculate SVD for a 100x2 matrix in an R script. What's funny is that doing the exact same thing for the exact same matrix in the R prompt works perfectly.

These are the data:

```
       [,1] [,2]
  [1,]   5840    5
  [2,]   5840    6
  [3,]  14600    2
  [4,]   5840    5
  [5,]   5840    4
  [6,]   5840    5
  [7,]  14600    5
  [8,]  14600    8
  [9,]   5840    5
 [10,] 262144   11
 [11,]  66240    5
 [12,]  16560   14
 [13,]   5840    5
 [14,]   5840   17
 [15,]  16560    6
 [16,]   5840    7
 [17,]  66240    5
 [18,]   5840    7
 [19,]  33003    7
 [20,]  65535    7
 [21,]   5840    6
 [22,]  65535    7
 [23,]  65535    4
 [24,]  16560    4
 [25,]   5840    4
 [26,]  14600    9
 [27,]  65535    6
 [28,]  14600    8
 [29,]   8192    8
 [30,]  14600    5
 [31,]  14600    5
 [32,] 131072    8
 [33,]  14600   10
 [34,]  14600    5
 [35,]  14600    5
 [36,]  14600    5
 [37,]  14600    5
 [38,]  14600    8
 [39,]   8192    9
 [40,]   8192   16
 [41,]  65535    5
 [42,]  14600    5
 [43,]   6432    5
 [44,]  14600    5
 [45,]   5840    5
 [46,]  14600    5
 [47,]   8192    7
 [48,] 254992    5
 [49,]  14600    6
 [50,]   5840    7
 [51,]  14600    5
 [52,]   5840    6
 [53,]  16560    7
 [54,]  64860    6
 [55,]  14600    5
 [56,]  14600    5
 [57,]  14600    5
 [58,]  14600    5
 [59,]  14600    5
 [60,]  14600    5
 [61,]   5840    5
 [62,]  65535    4
 [63,]  14600    5
 [64,]  14600    5
 [65,]  14600    8
 [66,] 131328    5
 [67,]   5840    5
 [68,]  14600    5
 [69,]  14600    5
 [70,]  14600    5
 [71,]  14600    5
 [72,]  14600    5
 [73,]  14600    5
 [74,]   5840   19
 [75,]  14600    5
 [76,]   5840    5
 [77,]  14600    5
 [78,]  14600    5
 [79,]  14600    5
 [80,]  14600    5
 [81,]  14600    5
 [82,]  14600    5
 [83,]   5840    7
 [84,]  14600    5
 [85,]  66048   21
 [86,]  65535  159
 [87,]   6432    6
 [88,]  14600    5
 [89,]  65535    5
 [90,]   8192   10
 [91,]   5840    5
 [92,]  14600    5
 [93,]  14600    5
 [94,]  66048    8
 [95,]  14600    5
 [96,]  16560    5
 [97,]  14600    5
 [98,]  42900    6
 [99,]   8192    7
[100,]   8192    7
```

I'm using a subset of the columns, so the actual call I'm making is `svd(C[,1:i])` where `C` is the matrix I'm using and `i` equals 2 when this crashes.

I'm positive that the matrices in the script and in the prompt are the same (I printed them both to different files and diffed them out to make sure!)

So, what could be the problem here?

**EDIT**

```
dput(C[,1:i])

structure(c(5840, 5840, 14600, 5840, 5840, 5840, 14600, 14600, 
5840, 262144, 66240, 16560, 5840, 5840, 16560, 5840, 66240, 5840, 
33003, 65535, 5840, 65535, 65535, 16560, 5840, 14600, 65535, 
14600, 8192, 14600, 14600, 131072, 14600, 14600, 14600, 14600, 
14600, 14600, 8192, 8192, 65535, 14600, 6432, 14600, 5840, 14600, 
8192, 254992, 14600, 5840, 14600, 5840, 16560, 64860, 14600, 
14600, 14600, 14600, 14600, 14600, 5840, 65535, 14600, 14600, 
14600, 131328, 5840, 14600, 14600, 14600, 14600, 14600, 14600, 
5840, 14600, 5840, 14600, 14600, 14600, 14600, 14600, 14600, 
5840, 14600, 66048, 65535, 6432, 14600, 65535, 8192, 5840, 14600, 
14600, 66048, 14600, 16560, 14600, 42900, 8192, 8192, 5, 6, 2, 
5, 4, 5, 5, 8, 5, 11, 5, 14, 5, 17, 6, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 4, 
4, 4, 9, 6, 8, 8, 5, 5, 8, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 8, 9, 16, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 
8, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 19, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 5, 
21, 159, 6, 5, 5, 10, 5, 5, 5, 8, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7), .Dim = c(100L, 
2L))
```

Comment: can you add `print(C[,1:i])` before your svd call, to see which  input gives is producing the error?

Comment: That's what I posted, `print(C[,1:i])`.

Comment: Post the output of `dput(C[,1:i])`.

Comment: There it is. Sorry about the delay. I had to `scp` the files from work.

Comment: Assign the result of `dput` to an object `x`. Then both `svd(x, nu = 0L, nv = 0L)` and
`svd(x[,1:2], nu = 0L, nv = 0L)` work perfectly in `Rscript` and give identical results. So I would say that either you are not doing the same things in an interactive R and in Rscript

Comment: Right now I can't ssh into the machine that was giving me the error, so I'll try it on Monday at work. Thanks.

Comment: With those arguments it works, but I need eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

**Relates to error message of OP , not to specific context of OP.**

Error in svd(X, nu = 0L) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

Occurs when calculating LDA ..

If the explained variable / group only has one value in the data supplied ( invalid data ).